# Database design for a social networking site

Tags: database, database-design, social-networking

What are the Tables that would be present in a social networking site (ex: Twitter).

I have a users table as of now. How to keep track of followers and people I do follow?

- Should I maintain a separate table for followers and people I follow?
- What are the columns which would be there in those tables?

Please don't think this as Subjective/Off topic. As I am a beginner, I thought experts can guide me to get a good DB design?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try having a look at [Database Answers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm) in particular the data models. They have several different designs for various systems. This [one](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/social_networking/index.htm) is for a social networking site which may give you an idea of what's required.

You may want to search on SO for other social network database questions. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767034/social-networking-network-affiliations) that had a link to [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ikhnaton2/533233247/) showing a schema which appears to be from Facebook.

Your database design will be based around your system requirements. Without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve, it is difficult to give you the best design.

Comment: First two links are dead as of now.

Comment: You can still view the second design via wayback here... http://web.archive.org/web/20101122023638/http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/social_networking/index.htm

Comment: Would you use a separate database per user in such a design?

Answer (score 14):

You can create a separate table for follower/ followed `relationships`. So, when x follow y, create an entry with `follower_id = x.id followed_id = y.id`.

You can query the relationship table to look for all the users x has relations with by `select * from relationships where follower_id = x.id` or vice versa.

When/if x un-follow y, you just have to delete the entry you originally created.

Answer (score 14):

you can use this Messenger Database Design Concept: [Messenger DB](https://github.com/yoosuf/Messenger)

[image: Messenger DB Schema]

Comment: Nothing in this data model addresses the question of how to model followers and followees

Comment: This concept is not a full and complete design, that is just Database Design Concept :)

Comment: password varchar(40) looks like SHA1 - you would need 60 bytes for bcrypt nowadays.  plus varchar(20) for last name is rather on the small side.  i have a friend whose last name is at least 30 characters.