# kotlin indexOf performance

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, indexof

I currently build an instagram like app. So there are posts in home page,which each post has likes. Likes array contains User data classes that has fields like, `name,username,age` and so on.

```
data class User(
    val id:String,
    val username: String?,
    val fullname: String?,
    val email: String?,
    val bio: String?
}
```

In recycler view adapter, i am checking if, user i logged in exists in likes array, if exists, i change the like icon as liked.
But i think `indexOf` function checks all of the fields User data class has, which is not performance wise i think.

What would be better option to use, like implementing own function or something else? (assume that there will be like 1k likes for each post,and is it performance wise to check if my user id exists in these likes array that contains more than 1k likes)

Comment: I think kotlin is using default equals function when you call indexOf and since comparing data classes means comparing their respective fields it would check the all field as you mentioned. So, under the assumption of every user have different id, you may want to override the equals method and only check whether ids match or not or I don't know would it be faster but you may use list.filter { it.id == <id_you_have>}

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to rely on a database for something like this, rather than just arrays of objects?

Comment: @Michael  actually i can shrink likes array to array of only ids, but your option is much better i think, how can i achieve that kind of result using database or server?do you know any resource? ( i built my server using node js and mongodb)

Comment: You can take a look at [some existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844477/social-web-application-database-design-how-can-i-improve-this-schema) for ideas on [how one might design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271182/database-design-for-a-social-networking-site) a database for a social network-type application.

Comment: For the question at hand you only need to change the behavior of your equals and hashCode method. It is the universal way to determine if two objects contains the same data.

Comment: @Michael can you please look at the [image here](https://pasteboard.co/JU6z1zq.png) , i've located logic inside server(assuming there will not be likes more than 1k)